# Apple SSO breaks after Django 4 upgrade

Tags: django, apple-sign-in, django-4.0, django-upgrade, django-4.1

After upgrading from django 3 to django 4, the "Sign in with Apple" feature started breaking with the following error

> Your request could not be completed because of an error. Please try again later.

[image]

The javascript, the frontend html, and the Apple ID url are all identical, and there is no useful error in the console. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that Django 4 added a new setting called [SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#secure-cross-origin-opener-policy) which sets the [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy) header to `same-origin`.

Adding the following line to my django settings module resolved the issue for me

```
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = "same-origin-allow-popups"
```

I am not sure why they did this because the default browser value is `unsafe-none`, and the browser error console was not very helpful.